# How to pass variable value from web form to another web page via controller class?

Tags: java, spring, getter-setter

Main class:

```
package com.example.handlingformsubmission;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class HandlingFormSubmissionApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
SpringApplication.run(HandlingFormSubmissionApplication.class, args);
}

}
```

Controller:(here in Post mapping something wrong with code which is supposed to pass values of variable to another page, but it doesn't):

```
package com.example.handlingformsubmission;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@Controller
public class GreetingController {

@GetMapping("/z.html")
public String greetingForm(Model model) {
model.addAttribute("z.html", new Greeting());
return "z.html";
}
@GetMapping("/zu.html")
public String greetingForm2(Model model) {
model.addAttribute("zu.html", new Greeting());
return "zu.html";
}

@GetMapping("/zus.html")
public String greetingForm3(Model model) {
model.addAttribute("zus.html", new Greeting());
return "zus.html";
}

@GetMapping("/zusu.html")
public String greetingForm4(Model model) {
model.addAttribute("zusu.html", new Greeting());
return "zusu.html";
}
@PostMapping("/zusu_generated.html")
public String greetingSubmit(@ModelAttribute Greeting greeting, Model model) {
model.addAttribute("zusu_generated.html",greeting);
model.addAttribute("Unit", greeting.getUnit());
model.addAttribute("Restarttype", greeting.getRestarttype());
return "zusu_generated.html";
}

}
```

Class where variables are declared (and getters and setters are configured):

```
package com.example.handlingformsubmission;
public class Greeting {
public String Restarttype;
public String Unit;

public String getRestarttype() {
return Restarttype;
}

public void setRestarttype(String Restarttype) {
this.Restarttype = Restarttype;
}

public String getUnit() {
return Unit;
}

public void setUNIT(String Unit) {
this.Unit = Unit;
  }
}
```

HTML web page where web form accepts values of variable:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>

    <html xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns:form="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <title>Getting Started: Handling Form Submission</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css" />
    <style type="text/css">

    .block1 {
    width: 20px;
    background: #ffffff;
    padding: 5px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    border: solid 1px white;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 17%; /* Отступ сверху */
    }

    .block2 {
    width: 1360px;
    background: #ffffff;
    padding: 5px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    border: solid 1px black;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 17%; /* Отступ сверху */
    text-align:center;
    }

    .block3 {
    width: 20px;
    background: #ffffff;
    padding: 5px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    border: solid 1px white;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 17%; /* Отступ сверху */
    }

   a.hover: underline(none)

    </style>


    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="block1"></div>
    <div class="block2">
        <h1>Nokia BSC3i ZUSU command</h1>

        <form action="#" th:action="@{/zusu_generated.html}" th:object="${greeting}" method="post">
            <table align = center>

                <tr>
                    <td> ZUSU:</td>
                <td>
                    <label for="Unit">Unit:</label>
                    <select name="Unit" id="Unit">
                        <optgroup label="Unit">
                            <option value="BCSU">BCSU</option>
                            <option value="Clock">Clock</option>
                            <option value="ET">ET</option>
                        </optgroup>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                C
                </td>
                <td> = </td>
                <td>
                    <label for="Restart value"> </label>
                    <select name="Restart type" id="Restart value">
                        <optgroup label="Restart type">
                            <option value="TOT">TOT</option>
                            <option value="HALF">HALF</option>
                            <option value="PARTIAL">PARTIAL</option>
                        </optgroup>
                    </select>
                </td>

                </tr>
            </table>
            <p><input type="submit" value="Generate command" /> <input type="reset" value="Reset" 
    /></p>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="block3"></div>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

HTML web page where variable values should appear, but they don't appear:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>

    <html xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns:form="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <title>Getting Started: Handling Form Submission</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css" />
    <style type="text/css">

   .block1 {
    width: 20px;
    background: #ffffff;
    padding: 5px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    border: solid 1px white;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 17%; /* Отступ сверху */
    }

   .block2 {
    width: 1360px;
    background: #ffffff;
    padding: 5px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    border: solid 1px black;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 17%; /* Отступ сверху */
    text-align:center;
    }

   .block3 {
    width: 20px;
    background: #ffffff;
    padding: 5px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    border: solid 1px white;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 17%; /* Отступ сверху */
    }

   a.hover: underline(none)

    </style>


    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="block1"></div>
    <div class="block2">
        <h1>Nokia BSC3i ZUSU command</h1>

        <form action="#" th:action="@{/greeting}" th:object="${greeting}" method="post">
            <table align = center>

                <tr>
                    <td>ZUSU:</td>
                    <td>
                        <label for="Unit">Unit:</label>
                        <select name="Unit" id="Unit">
                            <optgroup label="Unit">
                                <option value="BCSU">BCSU</option>
                                <option value="Clock">Clock</option>
                                <option value="ET">ET</option>
                            </optgroup>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        C
                    </td>



                    <td> = </td>
                    <td>

                        <label for="Restart value"> </label>
                        <select name="Restart type" id="Restart value">
                            <optgroup label="Restart type">
                                <option value="TOT">TOT</option>
                                <option value="HALF">HALF</option>
                                <option value="PARTIAL">PARTIAL</option>
                            </optgroup>
                        </select>
                    </td>

                </tr>
                <tr>

                    <td>
                        <p th:text="'Generated command is: ZUSU: UNIT = ' + ${greeting.Unit} + ' C = ' + ${greeting.Restarttype}" />

                    </td>
                </tr>

            </table>
            <p><input type="submit" value="Copy to memory" /> <input type="reset" value="Reset" /> 
    </p>
        </form>



    </div>
    <div class="block3"></div>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I believe that issue is somewhere in the part of code here:

Comment: @PostMapping("/zusu_generated.html")
public String greetingSubmit(@ModelAttribute Greeting greeting, Model model) {
model.addAttribute("zusu_generated.html",greeting);
model.addAttribute("Unit", greeting.getUnit());
model.addAttribute("Restarttype", greeting.getRestarttype());
return "zusu_generated.html";
}